# MySQL update price using SKU in WooCommerce

Tags: mysql, wordpress, woocommerce

I am trying to update prices in WooCommerce based on SKU. I have written some SQL but getting error 'You can't specify target table 'wp_postmeta' for update in FROM clause'. Is there any way to do the following better?

```
 UPDATE wp_postmeta SET meta_value = 144 WHERE 
meta_key = '_regular_price' AND 
post_id IN(SELECT post_id FROM wp_postmeta WHERE meta_key = '_sku' 
AND meta_value = SKU1451E51);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UPDATE wp_postmeta as pm
INNER JOIN wp_postmeta as pm2 on pm.post_id = pm2.post_id
SET pm.meta_value = 144
WHERE pm.meta_key = '_regular_price'
AND pm2.meta_key = '_sku' 
AND pm2.meta_value = 'SKU1451E51'
```

Comment: thanks a mil @mujuonly. this works fine. is it possible to add _price also? just like _regular_price? because the price to be changed are in both